# Using for loop along with range

Tags: for-loop, range

So I am working on an assignment in python where the goal is the user enters a number and then it displays the number with a general label (apples in this case), and then counts down from that number down to 1, with the label attached to each integer. What I have so far is :

```
x=int(input("How many apples?"))

for x in [range(x,0,-1)]:
    print(list(x),"apples")
```

So am looking for if user enters 10 that it would count down:

> 10 apples
>   9 apples
>   8 apples
>   etc

But I am getting  `[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] apples`

Been trying to arrange things different but can't seem to get it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem. The code `list(x)` is making a list, which in this case you don't need. Just do this:
`x=int(input("How many apples?"))`
`for x in range(0, x, -1):
    print(x+" apples")`

If you need anything else in Python, let me know- I've been using Python for 6 years.

Comment: I was able to get it using, x=int(input("How many apples?"))

for x in range(x, 0, -1):   
    print(x,"apples")     # thanks!

Comment: I believe the brackets around the range in my initial work messed things up as well?